# When will the on-topic FAQ go live?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, on-topic

We've discussed [what it should contain](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-should-our-on-topic-faq-contain), and [come up with a draft](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232/on-topic-faq-draft)...

Those posts were last active 5 months ago. I recently consulted the page to check if a question would be on topic, but it's still blank!

So, when does it get added to the official ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done. I did make a couple minor changes based on what was/was not in the existing template.

---

If users are fine with the draft at hand, we can do it now.

There was some support for minor edits, but not much discussion since then.

I'd rather put it up now, and if edits are desired (such as adding links) and get enough support individually, then editing the page later.

Comment: Looking good! I like it :D